# Integral of exponential of quadratics + exponentials

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration, approximation-theory, gaussian

Eq 2 of [this paper](http://amath.colorado.edu/pub/wavelets/papers/BEY-MON-2010.pdf) states this integral:
\begin{align*}
r^{-\beta} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-re^t + \beta t} dt
\end{align*}
Is there is name for this identity, or the class of identities of this form? And are there generalizations? I am dealing with a problem that requires computation of
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}\exp\left(-\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}_i^\intercal \mathbf{t}}\right\} + \boldsymbol{\alpha}^\intercal \mathbf{t} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^\intercal \Gamma \mathbf{t}\right) d\mathbf{t}
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_i \ge 0$ and $\boldsymbol{\theta}_i, \boldsymbol{\alpha}, \mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\Gamma \in \mathbf{R}^{p\times p}$. I'm willing to also settle for a very good approximation, if such exists.

Comment: The first formula can be obtained by a change of variable from the
integral definition of $\Gamma(\beta)$ (let $re^t = x$).  
But putting a $t^2$ term in the exponent probably makes things 
much harder even before you generalize to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: You can use Markov Chain Monte Carlo to estimate this integral — at the price of Monte Carlo statistical error which might be very large, but is independent of p.